# Read an IP address from one file, then lookup that IP in another file and printout the correspondent interface

Tags: python

Please pardon my very limited knowledge on Python. I am totally a newbie to programming. I have two txt files. One called "ips.txt" and the other one called "l2circuitconfig.txt". "ips.txt" has 3 ip addresses and "l2circuitconfig.txt" has configurations for more than 1000 ip addresses/lt interfaces. I have to write a code to read the ips from "ip.txt", then look into "l2circuitconfig.txt" for that perticluar ip address and print out the corresponding "lt" interface listed in that file.

Contents of the "ips.txt" file:

```
10.254.1.31
10.254.1.47
10.254.2.53
```

Contents of the "l2circuitconfig.txt" file:

```
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 static incoming-label 1001031 outgoing-label 790833
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 virtual-circuit-id 1001031
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 protect-interface lt-7/0/0.0
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 static incoming-label 1001047 outgoing-label 790855
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 virtual-circuit-id 1001047
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 protect-interface lt-7/0/0.1
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 static incoming-label 1002053 outgoing-label 791123
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 virtual-circuit-id 1002053
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 protect-interface lt-7/3/0.1
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan
```

Kind Rgds,
Rutvij

As i am a newbie, i only know how to read a file.

Have now written anything yet.

I expect out to be something like below:

```
10.254.1.31 - lt-5/2/0.20
```

Comment: Content of the file "ips.txt"
10.254.1.31
10.254.1.47
10.254.2.53

Comment: Contents of the file "l2circuitconfig.txt"
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 static incoming-label 1001031 outgoing-label 790833
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 virtual-circuit-id 1001031
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 protect-interface lt-17/2/0.20
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.31 interface lt-5/0/0.0 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan

Comment: set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 static incoming-label 1001047 outgoing-label 790855
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 virtual-circuit-id 1001047
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 protect-interface lt-17/0/0.40
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.1.47 interface lt-5/0/0.1 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan

Comment: set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 static incoming-label 1002053 outgoing-label 791123
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 virtual-circuit-id 1002053
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 protect-interface lt-17/3/0.190
set logical-systems INNI01-ls protocols l2circuit neighbor 10.254.2.53 interface lt-5/3/0.1 encapsulation-type ethernet-vlan

Comment: plz add this in your question

Comment: Added.. Thanks Asif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make an ip list from ips.txt then check in l2circuitconfig.txt . where regex is used to find ip from each line:

```
import re
ipList = []
with open('ips.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ipList.append(line.strip())

with open('l2circuitconfig.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        ipAddr = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line )[0]
        if ipAddr in ipList:
            d = line.split()
            print(d[6], '-', d[8])
```